# GetKeyBoardState() always shows some keys were pressed even though they were not after randomly pressing keyboard for a while

Tags: go, sdl

I am currently learning Go and trying to make a game which allows players to press several buttons at the same time. Right now, my code works for a while, but sometimes when I randomly press, the GetKeyboardState() always records one or more keys as pressed. The weird key only can be released when I press the key again. Then everything goes correctly again.
For example, I randomly press Up, Down, Left, Right, and right shift bottom on the keyboard to control the character in the game. Suddenly, the character always tries to go right and if I press Up or Down arrow, the character will just go to the top right or the bottom right. Only if I press the right arrow button again, the character can stop go right.

I thought maybe the game goes too fast so I limit the fps under 90 but the situation still exists.

Also, I tried to print out the keyboard status and it always shows the weird bottom was pressed when the situation happened even if I did not touch my keyboard.

```
func GetInput(keyState []uint8, prevKeyState []uint8) []Input {
   input := make([]Input, 0)
   if keyState[sdl.SCANCODE_UP] != 0 {
       input = append(input, Input{Up})
   }
       ...
   // Handle Down, Right, Left
   if keyState[sdl.SCANCODE_RSHIFT] == 0 && prevKeyState[sdl.SCANCODE_RSHIFT] != 0 {
       input = append(input, Input{RShift})
   }
   if keyState[sdl.SCANCODE_B] == 0 && prevKeyState[sdl.SCANCODE_B] != 0 
       {
       input = append(input, Input{Debug})
   }

   // something like prevKeyState = keystate
   return input
}
```

How I use it

```
keyState := sdl.GetKeyboardState()
prevKeyState := make([]uint8, len(keyState))
for {
    ...
    input := ui.GetInput(keyState, prevKeyState)
    HandleInput(input, board)
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you update state array? Is your event update locked to graphics thread?

Comment: @keltar: I only call GetkeyboardState() once at the very the beginning before the main game loop and assign it to keyState which I thought should be a []uint8. Then I do not modify it anymore because I think every input is directly updated through the address. I just read the keyState through the GetInput() function and check which key has been pressed at the beginning of the main game loop like the code above. I did not use an event to check keyboard input and if it is locked, why could I go back to normal through pressing the "wired key" again? I was confused.

Comment: To get keyboard state array updated you have to trigger SDL's internal event processing, e.g. via `SDL_PumpEvents` (or `SDL_PollEvent`, which calls pump internally).